# Redirecting stdout to mysql in bash

Tags: mysql, bash, pipe, io-redirection

I can execute mysql passing in a file as follows.

```
mysql -u username -p < some_file
```

In a bash script I have a function which echoes output which I want to pass into the same command in a bash script.

```
some_function() {
    echo "Some SQL"
}
```

How can I pass the output into mysql using pipes/redirection?

I have tried the following, but it fails with no such file or directory. How can I use the output from the function here instead.

```
mysql -u username -p < some_function
```

Comment: Use the pipe operator: `some_function | mysql -u username -p`.

Comment: @Amadan that's exactly what I was after, thank you.

Comment: @Amadan Using pipe or redirection make no sense in that case, see my answer to get more details ;)

Comment: @IdrissNeumann I’d rather presume that the function in question is a simplification of the real function, not a literal one-line `echo`, or OP wouldn’t have bothered with a function.

Comment: @Amadan This doesn't bring a justification to not use the `-e` option. You can catch the output of your function and passing it as argument like this `sql_command="$(your_function)"; mysql -u username -p -e "${sql_command}" database_name;`

Comment: @IdrissNeumann Sure you can. To what benefit, though? It is longer than a pipe, less straightforward than a pipe, invokes an additional shell process when compared to the pipe, and OP asked in the question for a pipe or redirection. Why so vehemently against pipes?

Comment: @Amadan I'm not vehement and anti-pipes. Let's just say that when a program or framework provides some features for a specific purpose it's always better to use them to achieve that purpose. There often are reasons to make these features available. This is exactly the same argument as the famous "never use values concatenation in a SQL queries and to use the parameterized queries features of your ORM".

Comment: This is getting ridiculous now. Piping into `mysql` is the primary method of restoring a `mysql_dump`, by the mysql manual. It is not a third party functionality, but a built-in mechanism made and supported by the same people who designed the `-e` switch. As such, it makes sense to use `-e` for short, static pieces of SQL, and pipe/redirection for longer or dynamic ones. It is by no means parallel argument to using parametrised statements.

Comment: @Amadan Hum I think there's also an option to source MySQL dump or SQL files and avoid to use a pipe to achieve that. Anyway I gave my opinion about privileging the use of the features provided by a program to achieve some specific purposes. I didn't say that you should never use pipes or using it in this case will not work. I don't think that's a ridiculous point of view, and no need to get disrespectful.

Answer (score 0):

No need to use a pipe or a redirection in this case, you can use directly `-e` options to execute some SQL commands:

```
mysql -u username -p -e "SQL/MySQL commands"
```

Exemple on a specific database:

```
mysql -u username -p -e "use database_name; SHOW tables"
mysql -u username -p -e "SHOW tables" database_name
```

And you can also catch the output of a command or function and passing it as argument like this:

```
sql_command="$(your_function)"
mysql -u username -p -e "${sql_command}" database_name;
```

If you really want to use a pipe or a redirection (but I think it make no sense in this case):

```
$ mysql -u root -p database_name < <(echo "SHOW TABLES") # redirection
$ mysql -u root -p database_name <<< "$(echo "SHOW TABLES")" # another way to use redirection
$ echo "SHOW TABLES"|mysql -u root -p database_name # pipe
```

Comment: Thanks for this, but I was trying to do it using the stdout created by a function, not a string that I already know.

Comment: @user3130010 This doesn't bring a justification to not use the `-e` option. You can catch the output of your function and passing it as argument like this `sql_command="$(your_function)"; mysql -u username -p -e "${sql_command}" database_name;`

Comment: @user3130010 I've edited my answer with two other possible way to redirect the output of command into another (but I continue to think that using `-e` would be a better choice in this specific case).